# Simple submodules over a semisimple ring are simple rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a semisimple ring. Consider a simple $R$-module, $E.$ I want to show that $E$ is a simple ring. That is, $E$ is semisimple and $|Irr(E)| = 1.$ $E$ has a ring structure as it is a direct summand of $R$. Furthermore, since $R$ is semisimple, $E$ is semisimple. We now have to show $|Irr(E)| = 1$. However, any proper two-sided ideal is a $R$-submodule of $E.$ Thus, we can see that there are no proper two-sided ideals as $E$ is a simple $R$-module. Thus, $|Irr(E)| = 1.$

Is this  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is false.

Let $R=M_2(F)$ and consider the simple right module $\begin{bmatrix}F&F\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

As you say it "has a rng structure" because it is a right ideal of $R$, but it can't be simple: it contains a proper ideal $\begin{bmatrix}0&F\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

The problem with your reasoning is, as you see, that not every ideal of $\begin{bmatrix}F&F\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is an $R$ submodule.

I thought representation theorists primarily worked in rings with identity... I'm not sure if this factors into your considerations or not. The ring above does not have an identity.

Now, if you take a simple right $R$ module $S$ and you consider the sum of minimal right ideals of $R$ isomorphic to $S$, you get an ideal of $R$ which is a direct summand and is indeed a simple ring (with identity.) Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Doesn't $R$ contain the identity matrix which acts as an identity? I can see how not every ideal of the simple module is an $R$-submodule. The reason why I ask this question is because I am trying to prove the Artin Wedderburn theorem with a specific lemma.
The lemma is, if $R$ is simple then $R \cong End_D(E)$ for $D$ a division ring and $E$ a simple $R$-module.
So because $R$ is semisimple, $R \cong E_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus E_n$ so I am trying to show the result of the theorem by proving that each $E_i$ is isomorphic to $End_D(E)$ by proving it is a simple ring. Is there a more correctway?

Comment: $R$ has an identity. The submodule does not contain an identity element.  Showing that $End_D(E)$ is simple if you know that the endomorphism ring of a finite dimensional vector space over a division ring is a square matrix ring over the division ring, which is simple (proven in several other posts on the site.) What would you like to do now, then?

Comment: Hmm how about this. $R = \oplus R_{\pi}$ where $R_{\pi}$ is the isotypic component for $\pi \in Irr(R).$ Each $R_{\pi}$ is a simple ring and hence is isomorphic to $End_D(E).$ Done. Does that work?

Comment: Sorry but I have another question. I don't mean to pester. But is a simple module over a semisimple ring $R$ always a simple submodule of $R$? I think this is true because a simple module $E$ can be thought of as a quotient $R/I$ and since $R$ is a direct sum of simple modules, $R/I$ is a submodule of $R$ itself.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Yes, the isotypic components are simple rings. That's what I mentioned in the last paragraph of the solution.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 But is a simple module over a semisimple ring R always a simple submodule of R? Yes, every simple right module appears as a minimal right ideal of $R$, for basically the reason you gave.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I hope you have a great day.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 You too! ${}{}{}$